# How to define a set of items based on constrains of a 2-tuple made of elements of other sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, combinations

imagine that I have the following sets:

$S = \{V_1, V_2, \dots, V_N\}$
$A = \{0, 1, 2, \dots, M\}$
$B = \{0, 1, 2, \dots, K\}$

and a table as follows:

| elements of S $s_i$ | elements of A $C_1(s_i)$ | elements of B $C_2(s_i)$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $V_1$ | 0 | 2 |
| $V_2$ | 1 | 2 |
| $V_3$ | 3 | 0 |
| $V_4$ | 1 | 2 |
| $V_5$ | 1 | 2 |

As you can see, more than one sample may belong to the same 2-tuple $(a_m, b_k)$, let $a_m$ and $b_k$ elements of $A$ and $B$ respectively (e.g. $V_2, V_4, V_5$).
I would like to define and write down in a mathematical notation, a set of elements the samples $s_i$ which belong to the same combination of 2-tuple $(a_m, b_k)$.
In this example I would get $\{V_2, V_4, V_5\}, \{V_3\}, \{V_1\}$.
What I did is something like this:
A subset $S_p$ of $S$ could be $S_p := \{s_i \mid (C_1(s_i), C_2(s_i)) \text{ are identical}\}$
My problem is that I need a mathematical description, not in plain English and that I have the intuition that I need to add a second constrain about the i but I am not sure. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your random use of indices makes your question difficult to decipher, but here is my attempt.

Let $S = \{s_1, \ldots, s_n\}$, $A_1 = \{1, \ldots, n_1\}$ and $A_2 = \{1, \ldots, n_2\}$. Let also $C_1: S \to A_1$ and $C_2: S \to A_2$ be two maps. Your apparently want to define, for each $(a_1, a_2) \in A_1 \times A_2$, the following subset of $S$
$$
S_{a,b} = \{ s_i \in S \mid C_1(s_i) = a_1 \text{ and } C_2(s_i) = a_2\}
$$
In your example, $n = 5$, $n_1 = 3$, $n_2 = 2$.  Moreover, $C_1(s_1) = 0$, $C_1(s_2) = C_1(s_4) = C_1(s_5) = 1$, $C_1(s_3) = 3$ and $C_2(s_1) = C_2(s_2) = C_2(s_4) = C_2(s_5) = 2$ and $C_2(s_3) = 0$. Then you would have $S_{1,2} = \{s_2, s_4, s_5\}$,
$S_{0,2} = \{s_1\}$ and $S_{3,0} = \{s_3\}$.